# How to Format Nullable object?

Tags: c#

This is a case I run into frequently and I was wondering if anyone had a better more concise way of doing this.

Say I have a variable 'x' which is of a type that is nullable. For example: string, int?, or DateTime?

I want to do something with x where I need to format x into a string but I cannot call .ToString() or some other method on x because x might be null.

Yes, I can do something like

```
if(x == null)
{
 Console.WriteLine("empty");
}
else
{
 Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("G"));
}
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", x == null? "empty" : x.ToString("G"));
```

but I was looking for something shorter. Maybe nothing exists, but I thought I would ask and start the conversation.

One reason I'm interested in this is because I frequently have a large number of variables where I'm moving data from one class to another or something similar and I need to apply some formatting.

So instead of just x, I've got a, b, c, ... z and I have to check each for null and apply formatting to each and they are of varios types and require different formatting. Something shorter and easier to copy and paste with only minimal changes to each line would be nice.

So does anyone have any clever tricks they use for this?

I also considered the ?? operator but I can't seem to find any good way to apply it. On first glance, it seems like it was designed just for this situation but it doesn't actually help at all.

Its really only useful so long as you don't need to apply any formatting.

Comment: Do you want it to say `empty` or do you want it to be blank?  `Console.WriteLine("{0:G}", x)` should work unless you really want the `empty`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine is probably a bad example but it was a function many people are familiar with. That is why I added the 'empty' to signify a case where you want something other than blank. Another example might be where you are using an XmlWriter and you are calling WriteElementString("elementname", x) and x is a DateTime?. I need to format x if it isn't null but if it is then I either want to pass null or maybe a blank string

Comment: Just encapsulate whatever logic you want in a method and then reuse the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generic helper:

```
public static class NullableHelper
{
    public static string ToString<T>(this T? x, string format) where T: struct 
    {
        return x.HasValue ? string.Format(format, x.Value) : null;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
int? i = 1;
i.ToString("{0:000}");
```

Comment: This won't work because C# will choose methods on the class before extension methods when looking for the `ToString` method to call.

Comment: nullable object has only one ToString method and it does not have any parameters

Comment: You're right.  Sorry, I assumed that your format parameter was optional.

Answer (score 2):

Write  a wrapper method

```
    public static string MyToString(MyType? x, string emptyString, string format)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return emptyString;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((MyType)x).ToString(format);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: add example with `x.GetValueOrDefault( 0 )`

Comment: This doesn't work because you didn't format x but you only supplied the if x is null string.

Comment: It needs a return type string as well.

Answer (score 1):

For nullable types you can try :

```
int? i;
i= null;

i.HasValue ? i.ToString() : "empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? a = null;
    string b = "my string";
    object c = null;
    // prints empty 
    Console.WriteLine(a.MyToString());
    // prints my string
    Console.WriteLine(b.MyToString());
    // prints empty
    Console.WriteLine(c.MyToString());
    // prints variable a doesn't have a value either
    Console.WriteLine(c.MyToString(callback: () => !a.HasValue ? "variable a doesn't have a value either" : DecoratorExtensions.MY_DEFAULT));
}

public static class DecoratorExtensions
{
    public const string MY_DEFAULT = "empty";

    public static string MyToString<T>(this T obj, string myDefault = MY_DEFAULT, Func<string> callback = null) where T : class
    {
        if (obj != null) return obj.ToString();
        return callback != null ? callback() : myDefault;
    }

    public static string MyToString<T>(this T? nullable, string myDefault = MY_DEFAULT, Func<string> callback = null) where T : struct
    {
        if (nullable.HasValue) return nullable.Value.ToString();
        return callback != null ? callback() : myDefault;
    }
}
```